# Open Word document in browser (Google Chrome) instead of downloading (with PHP)

Tags: php, browser, ms-word

Is there way to tell browser (i care mainly about Google Chrome which looks to have "Microsoft Office 2010" plugin) to open Microsoft Word document inside of browser using PHP?

RESULT: all tries made browser to download file. Looks like this Chrome plugin serves for something else than rendering .doc files.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `Content-Disposition` to inline

```
header("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.ext")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set the MIME type properly and then set the `Content-Disposition` header to `inline`.

```
<?php
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=blah.doc');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create redirect to google docs viewer with URL of the file in GET request.

For example, if you wanted to view the PDF at the URL http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf , you would use the URL: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf

Comment: ah sorry - misunderstood your question ;)